# Windows 8 right click on desktop bugs

Tags: windows-8, right-click

I have upgraded my windows 7 to windows 8 and i got some issue when I make right click on desktop it stuck there , the mouse still loading and nothing happend.

Here is an example :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=slMGcCxXuDE

For me it take over 2min :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling any programs that entered entries in the right click menu (they may have displayed in Windows 7 but fail to load in windows 8, assuming you did an upgrade install and not a format/clean install). For example, 7zip and WinRAR put entries in the right click menu. You can always just install them afterwards again if it makes no difference, or if it does make a difference, you can download the latest version of the program and try to install it again.